# What is the image on many volumes of Shas called?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, pictures

Does anyone know the official name of the 4-poled structure in the middle of the image below (of a cover of a volume of the Talmud)? I'm pretty sure that this 'structure' has a name, but my intense googling yielded no results, so I posted here.  Just curious.

[image: ![Artscroll Talmud Bavli]

Comment: I always thought it was an old school chupah symbolizing how we are married to Hashem through the torah. Gate is nice too, though.

Comment: @Rafael I made some minor edits to make it flow as one smooth question, and to state what the image is (some users might not be able to see it). Feel free to edit it yourself if you don't like what I've done.

Comment: (I thought we had this question already.) Wouldn't canopy work?

Comment: @DoubleAA, While it may be a canopy, I'm looking for a more _specific_ name of a image found in many volumes of Shas.

Comment: @Rafael you mean like "Jim"? Why would this image have a proper name?

Comment: @DoubleAA, 1. I seem to recall that it has a name, and 2. It's unlikely that an image found in many volumes of Shas _wouldn't_ have a proper name to it.

Comment: Are you curious about how is it called or what does it depict?

Comment: @Kazibácsi, I was more interested on what it's called, but I'd like to know a source for it to.

Comment: @rosends I do like the chuppah interpretation. But it being a gate doesn't mean it loses significance: (פִּתְחוּ־לִ֥י שַֽׁעֲרֵי־צֶ֑דֶק אָֽבֹא־בָ֜֗ם א֘וֹדֶ֥ה יָֽהּ (תהלים קיח, יט

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always heard it called the "Sha'ar Vilna". Sha'ar means "gate" in Hebrew.

Comment: Why the deletion vote? Is it because it's so simple or obvious? Apparently it wasn't obvious to the OP, because he doesn't mention it and also doesn't mention that when you [search "שער וילנא" into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8+%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%90&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio-Lyu_I_dAhUKKawKHa7YDxoQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=887) it yields what he's looking for...

Comment: I searched too and it is exactly as you state Ezra. Vilna Gate,

Comment: @ezra, I accepted this answer over Kazi Bácsi's because it names the actual image, not just the name of the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As some searching resulted, the image is called *Shaar Blatt* (שער בלאט or literally *gate* page), and it was the cover page of the original Vilna edition of the Babylonian Talmud by Romm.

As Salamon's Temple had two big pillars ([Boaz and Yakhin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaz_and_Jachin)) and the ark of the Great and the Choral Synagogue in Vilna had a different design, it might be an allegory to the 50 gates of understanding described on [Rosh haShanah 21b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=21b&format=pdf).

Comment: "Shaar Blatt" means "title page". It refers to the title page of the book, not to the specific image.

Comment: @Menachem שער means gate. It might be an allusion to the 50 gates of understanding.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about putting that, but I thought title page was more of an indication of what it was.