# Are there formats/templates for seforim?

Tags: jewish-books, books-generally

I was wondering. There are many seforim which have the same lay-out as other seforim. It is usually places on the first pages of the sefer, and the same style is often placed on the cover.

Here's a example.

[image]

Picture from [Greenfield Judaica](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/beis-meir-al-hatorah-ostovtze-2-volume-set-902192.html)

[Or](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/chasam-sofer-al-hatorah-umoadim---mamarim-chadashim-523853.html):

[image]

**Does anyone know if there are templates/formats that one could use when writing his own sefer that look like this page?**

Since most publishers use this kind of layout, there must be a name for it :) (most of the times, the templates consists of a sort ["column", two that are standing next to each other, with text in the middle.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119998/27180))

Comment: On topic/allowed [as per this Meta-answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5545/27180)

Comment: I've noticed that the inside page of many gemarahs (and possibly other seforim) even from different publishers seem to have a similar picture of some kind of building with columns.  Always wondered if there is any significance to it.

Comment: @MosesSupposes Yes, [there is](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119998/27180)

Comment: For sure publishers, and book designers, use templates to speed up their work. If only by adapting from previous work. This leads to the consistency you mentioned. Not sure they would share them, but my experience preparing books for self-publication is that you are better off writing the content, and finding an expert to do the editing, typesetting, designing - will look out much better and more professional

Comment: Thanks, is there a name for it? Surely, if most publishers use the same-looking format, it must have a special name :) Gut Shabbos!